# Display all status messages of service in nagios xi

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

How shall I see all the status messages of a service in nagios xi. I send multiple status messages and the latest message is displayed in the dashboard UI. From where shall I retrieve all the previous messages?

Comment: You want show all previous messages within same state (critical, warning, etc..)?

Comment: Hey Rohlik. You are right. I wanted to show all the messages of a service/node in nagios.

Answer (score 0):

You need define `stalking_options` directive in your services/hosts definition.
Example:

```
define service {
  service_description            Users count
  host_name                      myhost1
  use                            service_standard
  check_command                  check_nrpe_custom!-H myhost1 -c check_user
  stalking_options               c,w,o,u
}
```

More info about `stalking_options` can be found [here](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/stalking.html).